# Session Storage with Redis Sentinel in PHP

Tags: php, session, redis, redis-sentinel

I'm currently working through the process of scaling out our server setup and we're to the point where we need to reconfigure the sessions to be stored in a high availability solution (having people logged out if a server goes down is not an option).  We're trying to use Redis because we're already using it for other parts of the site.  The trouble I run into is that there doesn't appear to be any [support](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/449#issuecomment-232469847) for this.  Before I create my own session handler class, I thought I would ask if anyone else knows if there is a project for this use case.

Comment: Can you not use rawCommand as mentioned in your link?

Comment: @ChrisTanner, I guess I'm looking for how I can set up the session handler.  I think, the rawCommand would only work outside of the sessions.

Comment: Hey @ScottKeck-Warren, did you get to resolve this? I'm in a similar place, where we need to use redis-sentinel but can't.

Comment: @droidbot I had to write my own session handler.  I documented how we switched without downtime on my blog at http://www.thisprogrammingthing.com/2017/migrating-sessions-in-php/ and it includes example code.

Comment: awesome.. thats handy @ScottKeck-Warren